# Ubuntu lags and overheats my laptop. Drives fans to max

Tags: nvidia, laptop, overheating

Laptop: Razer Blade 2017, i7-7700HQ / Nvidia GTX 1060 / 16gb RAM / 1 TB SSD (128gb Ubuntu, 896gb windows)

Ubuntu 17.10

Laptop lags and gets very noticeable frame drops when doing simple tasks such as browsing google chrome or using the file manager. Fans turn up to max during these simple tasks. Solutions on how to fix?

Comment: For myself nVidia in Linux drives me nuts and I turned it off in favour of Intel iGPU instead (`sudo prime-select intel`).

Answer (score 0):

I got gtx 1060 working with nvidia support and no issues so far on ubuntu 16.04 lts.

Steps are given below.

1. Create an ubuntu 16.04 lts usb installation using rufus and the ubuntu iso.
2. Follow any guide online to install it with dual boot.
3. Once it's installed, please DO NOT install nvidia drivers from the software updater or even any other noveau driver or whatever if you intend to use the gtx 1060 discrete gpu. Install ppa nvidia drivers using the terminal. Google for the commands. I used nividia-410 ppa drivers
4. You have to edit the grub file and add "nomodeset" parameter right after "quiet splash" like so: "quiet splash nomodeset"
5. Reboot.
6. Enjoy.